# Print falls off the bed the majority of the way through a print

Tags: 3d-models

I have an Anker Make M5, and I am trying to print something that uses the majority of the build height, its roughly a 7 h print, I got an alert 6 h in that there was an error, checked and the print was on the floor and filament spooling out.

I don't think it's an adhesion issue as smaller prints are fine, and before it came off there was no sign of lifting.

Does anyone know what could cause this and fix that issue? So far I have added a raft to prints and increased bed temperature to 70 °C.

Comment: Are you printing PLA? Please update by [edit].

Answer (score 1):

If a print falls over you have an adhesion issue. Do note that a raft is not the most sturdy support (depending on your options), there is always an air gap between the raft top surface and the bottom print surface. A raft is generally most useful when printing materials that have a considerable amount of shrinkage when cooling.

Increasing bed temperature might not be ideal either, depending on your material, if PLA, 70 °C may be too hot and thus too flexible.

Maybe a brim or adding "mouse ears" to your print help to improve adhesion.

Comment: So I should adjust the raft to be wider ? And the warmer bed was to prevent corners curling (which it did).

Comment: IMHO you should ditch the raft and use a brim.

Comment: done that and just started the print... we shall see in 7h.

Comment: @MrDDog Did it fall over?